# Change shape of a bezier after you've completed it

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve

I'm using the bezier tool, but I forgot the 'shape' option was set to an ellipse so my drawing is just a mess. Is there any way to change the shape option AFTER I've completed the curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the path and open the XML editor (*Edit -> XML Editor*).

You will note that there are more attributes in your path than on a simple path with no stroke shape.

In particular, click on `inkscape:path-effect` and delete it (there is an icon with a red cross nearby).

Then you have the `d` attribute, and the `inkscape:original-d` attribute. The latter contains your path, while the former contains the complete shape of the stroke.

Select the `inkscape:original-d` attribute, copy it's value, then select the `d` element and replace its value with the copied path. Save this new value with the *Set* button.

Now delete the `inkscape:original-d` attribute.

You may need to set *No-fill* and a stroke color to see the path as a line instead of a filled-in area.

Comment: Inkscape has a built-in command to remove a path effect from a selection - see menu **Path > Remove Path Effect**. Path effects can also be deleted in the **Path > [Path Effects](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects.html)** dialog.

Comment: @su_v please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: My comment is not really another answer to the original question «Is there any way to change the shape option» - it's only a variation of the existing answer to delete the path effect manually via XML Editor. An alternative answer might explain how to change the shape (aka pattern) e.g. of the Pattern-along-Path effect (Shape 'Ellipse') or how to adjust a Powerstroke path effect (Shape 'Triangle In' or 'Triangle out').